# play external video using unity and vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an android app using Vuforia SDK and unity.  When an image is scanned, I need to display the video from an external source like our own server.  How will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the `Cloud Reco` feature on Vuforia.

To get you started on Cloud Reco, refer [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tksyhVlIMQ)

Upload a target into Vuforia Database (Database should be for cloud reco. If not, create a new database for it) and get the Client Keys.

Now integrate the desired API of your external source and voila you've got your app.

Comment: Thanks for your prompet reply. Is the cloud Reco for the marker or for the video?
I am new to develop augmented reality apps and try to understand tools

Comment: Cloud Reco is for the Marker/Target. For the Video to play, you need to get the API of your External Source and place it according to the video in your Inspector Panel in Unity

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your patience. Please can you tell me how to get that API and how use it.

Comment: Click the link to the video for reference. If your external video player doesn't have an API, you will not be able to use it in the app.